# Unable to convert to a column data from string to number

Tags: pandas

The data from a file as follows.

| SNo | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 450 |
| 2 | 2,000 |
| 3 | 5,500 CR |

Due to ',' and ' CR' string in a column of data, the column data type is an object. I am able to extract the numbers from it by removing both strings but I am unable to multiply by -1 in case there is ' CR' in the string.

```
Combine['Amount_Sign'] = [sub.replace(' CR', '') for sub in Combine['Amount']]
Combine['Amount_Sign'] = [sub.replace(',', '') for sub in Combine['Amount_Sign']]
Combine['Amount_Sign'] = Combine['Amount_Sign'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Dataframe:

```
      j = pd.DataFrame({'SNo':[1, 2, 3],
                  'Amount':['450','2,000','5,500 CR']})

            SNo Amount
       0    1   450
       1    2   2,000
       2    3   5,500 CR
```

Do the transform to data in 'Amount' column:

```
      j['Amount'] = j['Amount'].apply(lambda x: \ 
          int(x.replace('CR','').replace(',','')))

     SNo    Amount
   0    1   450
   1    2   2000
   2    3   5500
```

Check the datatype of Amount column:

```
   j['Amount'].dtype
       dtype('int64')     <-- Converted to Int
```